# Having problems with angular on nginx with docker - swarm will not find service

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, swarm

I have written an app in angular that relies on a restful middle-ware layer which in turn contacts the business logic layer which manages the data on the database.

The infrastructure is as follows:

- Mysql handles persistence
- Business-logic on Tomcat 8.5.31
- Restful-middle-ware on Tomcat 8.5.31
- Front-end app on nginx 1.15.2 & angular 5

On my workstation everything works beautifully, however, after dockerizing all the services the front-end will not find the middle-ware services. below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  ngxseeker: # Front-end service Angular/nginx
    image: bilorge/seekr:ngxseekr-0.01
    networks:
      - pub # public facing nic
    ports:
      - 80:80

  ckerws: # Restful middle-ware service
    image: bilorge/seekr:seekr-web-0.01
    networks:
      - priv # private nic
      - pub # public facing nic

  seekr-service: # business logic server / data management
    image: bilorge/seekr:seekr-server-0.01
    networks:
      - priv # private nic

  ckerdb: # database / persistence layer
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - cker-db-data:/var/lib/mysql # persistent data storage
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=&*$#$^##
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - priv # private nic

networks: # nic definition
  pub:
    driver: overlay
  priv:
    driver: overlay

volumes:
    cker-db-data: # data volume definition
```

Its worth mentioning in order to make the application compatible to work docker and its services I added the service names to my hosts file on my work station. The entries were as follows:

- 127.0.0.1 ngxseeker
- 127.0.0.1 ckerws
- 127.0.0.1 seekr-service
- 127.0.0.1 ckerdb

this way when I run it locally on my workstation everything will resolve to the same service names inside the docker swarm. Again, all this works when I run it in my IDE or stand alone on my workstation.

Prior to running on swarm I comment the hosts entries to make sure they will not muddy the waters. when I deploy the stack (single node swarm) I wait and make sure all services are up and ready for work.

I then point my browser to 127.0.0.1 and get my app's landing page which greets me with login page. I provide the credentials and immediately fails. The developer tools indicate the post request goes out, but it never comes back.

I have verified the following:
 - Database has data
 - The business logic server is able to talk to the database
 - the middle ware server is able to resolve the business logic layer
 - the front end is able to resolve the middle-ware layer

On the last point I made a reverse proxy entry on ngix to hit the landing page for the Tomcat running the middle-ware layer and its successful. BTW, at boot up if nginx does not find the reverse proxy entries it will not start.

during a trouble shooting session I create a Ubuntu VM (latest) in Virtualbox with a bridged network as I wanted the vm get an ip from my router. I then deployed my stack, single node swarm, except for the front end which I was running from my work station. because the swarm was hosted externally I exposed port 8080 on the ckerws service. I also added a host entry for the vm and the service:

- 192.168.1.62 ckerws
- 192.168.1.62 poky

I fired up browser and pointed it to 127.0.0.1 as usual the landing page loads up, however, this time when I provided the credentials it worked! if I bring in all the service under one swarm then it breaks..

I'm stumped and not sure whats going on.. I have a feeling that it has to do we service scope resolution, however, I'm a bit out of my element there.

Comment: Did you try putting them on the same network, this looks like a network issue to me. Nginx is unable to find them (if you use it as a load balancer for instance)

Comment: You're not being charged by the letter here; If you want people to help you, give your services descriptive names written the in language you're asking for help in. I'm not going to try and guess what a 'ckerws' is or what it's supposed to do.

Comment: CantankerousBullMoose the service name is friendly, if you are familiar with the project. for instance cker (seeker) ws is short for web service. this is the nomenclature and honestly is irrelevant to the engine as it references the resource by its ID, a rather long hash. calling the service middleware-restfull-web-services seems wasteful and time consuming. In the effort for clarity here is the service definition.

ngxseeker: Angular front end on nginx
ckerws: seeker restful web service - middle-ware
seekr-service: business logic service, also resftul
ckerdb: databse persistance layer

Comment: Yamaç Kurtuluş Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried that its still failing to resolve the middle-ware service.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. The root of the problem had to do whit the routes in nginx. as the call came in to nginx there was no logic which would build a call the middle-ware service. In order to fix it I had to create a rule in nginx which would match the incoming call and do the reverse proxy action to the webservice. The other consideration to take when working with distributed applications.. be sure to code the correct endpoint name on the front-end app do it can build those urls correctly! I plan to make a video on this soon and I'll place the link here.